# Custom mix task not loading test environment

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am attempting to put together a custom mix task that will execute the `mix test` task in a specialized manner. My mix task is `mix test.pretty`.

So far, I've written the world's most basic custom mix task:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Test.Pretty do
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Simply runs the Hello.say/0 function"
  def run(_) do
    Mix.env(:test)

    Mix.Task.run("test", ["--formatter", "ExPrettyTest.Formatter"])
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I run the task (`mix test.pretty`) I get this error:

> ** (RuntimeError) cannot invoke sandbox operation with pool DBConnection.ConnectionPool. To use the SQL Sandbox, configure your
>   repository pool as:
>
> ```
> pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
>
> (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:491: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.lookup_meta!/1
> (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:389: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode/2
> (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
> (elixir) lib/enum.ex:765: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
> (elixir) lib/enum.ex:765: Enum.each/2
> (mix) lib/mix/tasks/test.ex:369: Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1
> (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:316: Mix.Task.run_task/3
> (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:79: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
> (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
> ```

It ***appears*** that the test environment isn't being loaded up--perhaps test_helper.exs hasn't been loaded?

I can run the task like so: `MIX_ENV=test mix test.pretty` and it works fine. I'd like to get this working w/o having to put MIX_ENV=test in there every time I run the task. In my head, the entire point of having a custom test was to avoid having to specify that environment and the formatter argument manually.

My workflow is to run `mix test`, if there are errors, I think run `mix test.pretty` which gives me sweet, awesome test output using the custom formatter mechanism in ExUnit. Once I've nailed down the errors, I can choose to run the file pretty or not, the individual test pretty or not, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting preferred_cli_env in your mix.exs file?

From:
https://hexdocs.pm/mix/master/Mix.Task.html

Probably something like:

```
preferred_cli_env: [
  "test.pretty": :test
]
```

in your `def project do ... end`

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks a TON.

Comment: No problem :). Just adding this here in case anyone wonders why you couldn't set it from the script. From the documentation: `@preferred_cli_env is not loaded from dependencies as we need to know the environment before dependencies are loaded. `